# Build all possible 3-column matrices from 3 input matrices of different sizes

Tags: r, matrix

I have three different matrices:

```
m1, which has 12 rows and 5 columns;
m2, which has 12 rows and 4 columns; and
m3, which has 12 rows and 1 column.
```

I'm trying to build a series of 3-column matrices (p1 to p20) from this, such that in each p matrix:

```
p[,1] is taken from m1,
p[,2] is taken from m2, and
p[,3] is taken from m3.
```

I want the process to be exhaustive, so that I create all 20 possible 3-column matrices, so sampling m1, m2, and m3 (a solution I already tried) doesn't seem to work.

I tried half a dozen different for loops, but none of them accomplished what I wanted, and I played with some permutation functions, but couldn't figure out how to make them work in this context.

Ultimately, I'm trying to do this for an unknown number of input matrices, and since I'm still new to R, I have no other ideas about where to start.    Any help the forum can offer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
## Example matrices
m1 <- matrix(1:4, nrow=2)
m2 <- matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
m3 <- matrix(1:2, nrow=2)

## A function that should do what you're after
f <- function(...) {
    mm <- list(...)
    ii <- expand.grid(lapply(mm, function(X) seq_len(ncol(X))))
    lapply(seq_len(nrow(ii)), function(Z) {
        mapply(FUN=function(X, Y) X[,Y], mm, ii[Z,])
    })
}

## Try it out
f(m1)
f(m1,m2)
f(m1,m2,m3)
```

Comment: +1 Very nice. I got as far as expand.grid, but in that time you wrapped the whole thing up into a very nice function

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem can be split into two parts:

1. Create all valid combination of indexes from 1:5, 1:4 and 1
2. Compute the matrices

For the first problem, consider a merge without common columns (also called a "cross join"):

```
merge(data.frame(a=1:5), data.frame(a=1:4), by=c())
```

Use a loop to construct a data frame as big as you need. **EDIT**: Or just use `expand.grid`, as suggested by Josh.

For the second problem, the `alply` function from the `plyr` package will be useful. It allows processing a matrix/data frame row by row and collects the results in a list (a list of matrices in your case):

```
alply(combinations, 1, function(x) { ... })
```

`combinations` is the data frame generated by `expand.grid` or the like. The function will be called once for each combination of indexes, `x` will contain a data frame with one row. The return values of that function will be collected into a list.